# Spring tries to instantiate the interface when injecting a parameter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I hope you can help me with this.

I'm using Spring MVC (3.1.1) in my web application, and am facing a strange situation.
I have this simple @Controller, that makes use of the ServicioUsuario Service, and works fine:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ajax")
public class ControladorAjax extends ControladorGenerico {

  @Autowired
  ServicioUsuario servicioUsuario;

  @RequestMapping("/check")
  public ResponseEntity<String> check(@RequestParam String email) {
    // Declarations and other operations omitted...
    // Use servicioUsuario
    servicioUsuario.doStuff();
    return response;
  }
}
```

However, if I remove the @Autowiring, and try to make Spring inject `servicioUsuario` as a parameter (i.e. by changing the method signature to: `public ResponseEntity<String> check(@RequestParam String email, ServicioUsuario servicioUsuario)`) the whole thing breaks, and I get this sort of exceptions in Tomcat's log:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: NestedServletException in java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace:: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.package.ServicioUsuario]: Specified class is an interface
```

I have these interfaces:

```
com.package
  |-> Servicio.java (interface)
  |-> ServicioUsuario.java (interface that extends Servicio)
```

and these clases:

```
com.package.impl
  |-> ServicioImpl.java (implements Servicio)
  |-> ServicioUsuarioImpl.java (@Service("servicioUsuario") that extends ServicioImpl implements ServicioUsuario)
```

and configured Spring to scan both packages with:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package
                                      com.package.impl" />
```

Why is Spring trying to instantiate the interface and not the implementing class? Is it something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't do that. Spring MVC controller method args are complex, you need to read the Spring docs to see how they are interpreted. In your example Spring is trying to use your class as a form backing bean, which requires a concrete class.

Comment: Did you try `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired`?

Comment: Why is it strange that it didn't work? I think the original way of injecting/autowiring the service into your controller is the normal way to do it.

Comment: @nickdos Well, I also tried explicitly defining the bean, as `<beans:bean id="servicioUsuario" class="com.package.impl.ServicioUsuarioImpl"/>` (thus not relying on Spring's component scan), so I'm telling Spring which is the concrete class for instantiating the bean.

Comment: @david It's strange, for me, since `public ResponseEntity<String> check(@RequestParam String email, ServicioUsuarioImpl servicioUsuario)`works as expected, and I simply wanted to make use of the corresponding interface instead of the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [*16.3.3.1 Supported method argument types*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) of the official documentation, this is a complete list of what controller methods can take:

> - Request or response objects (Servlet API). [...] for example `ServletRequest` or `HttpServletRequest`.
> - Session object (Servlet API): of type `HttpSession`.
> - `org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest` or `org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest`.
> - `java.util.Locale` for the current request locale [...]
> - `java.io.InputStream` / `java.io.Reader` for access to the request's content. [...]
> - `java.io.OutputStream` / `java.io.Writer` for generating the response's content. [...]
> - `java.security.Principal` containing the currently authenticated user.
> - `@PathVariable` annotated parameters for access to URI template variables. [...]
> - `@RequestParam` annotated parameters for access to specific Servlet request parameters. [...]
> - `@RequestHeader` annotated parameters for access to specific Servlet request HTTP headers. [...]
> - `@RequestBody` annotated parameters for access to the HTTP request body. [...]
> - `@RequestPart` annotated parameters for access to the content of a "multipart/form-data" request part. [...]
> - `HttpEntity<?>` parameters for access to the Servlet request HTTP headers and contents. [...]
> - `java.util.Map` / `org.springframework.ui.Model` / `org.springframework.ui.ModelMap` [...]
> - `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes` [...]
> - Command or form objects to bind request parameters to bean properties (via setters) or directly to fields, [...]
> - `org.springframework.validation.Errors` / `org.springframework.validation.BindingResult` [...]
> - `org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus` [...]
> - `org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder` [...]

As you can see, Spring beans are not on this (quite impressive) list. Why would you inject services via controller method? They never change. It's enough to inject them once and assign them to a field.

Comment: This list will come in handy :). However, Spring _can_ inject Spring beans. For example, if I simply change the method's signature to `public ResponseEntity<String> check(@RequestParam String email, ServicioUsuarioImpl servicioUsuario)`, it works, though I lose the loose coupling benefits from using interfaces.

Comment: @ahpoblete: interesting! Are you sure this is an instance of Spring bean (does it have wired dependencies) or maybe Spring just created an instance of this class blindly using reflection and nothing more? In other words it doesn't matter that `ServicioUsuarioImpl` is a Spring bean, you can put any other POJO there (?)

Comment: Also, just wanted to clarify that, since this will be the only method making use of that service, I wanted to scope it only to such method, and not to the whole @Controller, and let every method be responsible for their own dependencies.

Comment: You just made me wonder and test it... Well, servicioUsuario _is_ a Spring bean (and it depends on some other DAO services). I created a simple class Pojo, with `static int i = 0;` as an attribute, it's constructor increments it by 1: Spring creates a new instance of it on every method call. This happens as well when using `SerivcioUsuarioImpl` as an argument, but not when @Autowiring it (as it was expected)... So, to sum up: It doesn't matter if it is a Spring bean or not, any other POJO there works, except that Spring will create a new instance every time.

Comment: I get the feeling you are not using Spring the way its intended. Convention dictates you inject dependent services at the class level - Spring will create an instance (usually singleton) and then reference it for that class. If you inject at the method level, Spring is trying to instantiate and inject it for every call of that method, because according to this (answer's) list of method args, it is expecting the bean to be used for form-backing. You should be splitting your Controllers up according to their dependencies if you are that concerned about it.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's quite unconventional the way I'm trying to structure my Controller, and I think it won't work as I expected it to.